# Nested Extension Method does not work - Scala

Tags: scala, extension-methods, dsl, implicit-conversion, implicit

I create a simply Date DSL. My code is:

```
import java.time.{Year, LocalDate}

import Numeric.Implicits._

object Main {

  implicit def wrapMonth[A:Numeric](v: A) = new {
    def october = {
      def of(y: Integer) = {
        5
      }
      9
    }
  }

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    println(3.october of 2014)
  }
}
```

I have the error:

```
value of is not a member of Int
    println(3.october of 2014)
```

I dont understand, why this error happens, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following will work,

```
implicit def wrapMonth[A: Numeric](v: A) = new {
    def october = {
      9
    }
    def of(y: Integer) = {
      5
    }
  }
```

You cant call a nested method from outside. Its not visible.

**Edit**

```
implicit def wrapMonth(v: Int) = new {
  def october = {
    (v, 9)
  }
}

implicit def wrapDay(v: (Int, Int)) = new {
  def of(y: Int) = {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.set(y, v._2, v._1, 0, 0)
    c.getTime
  }
}
```

Comment: so, it is really works. But i dont understand, how to get entire data, when user write something like that: "3.october of 2014".

Comment: Whats your intended output?

Comment: any object of Date type (java Date or other Date).

Comment: see edit, its a naive implementation. output is `java.util.Date`. Also the month works there because we have set October as 9. If you are going to provide October as 10, use v-1